# Vb.net For loop creating odd numbed files

Tags: vb.net

Now I'm kind of new to coding and I saw some videos on Vb.net so I wanted to give it a chance and I'm trying to create multiple files at once so I thought I'd use a for loop

```
 My.Computer.FileSystem.CreateDirectory("game")
    For GameNumber As Integer = 0 To 32
        GameNumber = GameNumber + 1
        Dim GameName As String = "Game" + GameNumber.ToString()
        My.Computer.FileSystem.CreateDirectory("game/" + GameName)
    Next
    MessageBox.Show("Game created successfully!", "Success.")
```

But when I run this code it creates the files but only in odd number so it would go Game1, Game3, Game5, Game7.
Can someone take a look at my code and tell me what I am missing? Thank you very much.

Comment: Please read [ask] and take the tour.  You also need a [rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging)

Comment: BTW, if you ever want to only get the odd numbers, you'd use the [Step](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/for-next-statement) option on your loop like this: `For GameNumber As Integer = 1 To 33 Step 2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to have

```
GameNumber = GameNumber + 1
```

The For loop will automatically increment the value when you use Next

Answer (score 0):

The `For` loop iterates already, the culprit is the line `GameNumber = GameNumber + 1`... you are adding 1 more to GameNumber at every step.

First run of the loop: Gamenumber starts at 0, you add 1. So Game1 is output. The loop iterates; GameNumber is now 2. You add one, GameNumber is now 3, and Game3 is output.

Make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue lies in something I myself fell victim to just a few months ago.

The `For...Next` loop acts differently than a normal `Do...Loop` or `Do...While` or `Do...Until` loop in that it automatically increments your variable that controls the loop whereas in the others you have to manually enter the code of `counter = counter + 1` for it to proceed. You still have that line in your loop, so it increments by 2 each time it runs through your loop instead of by 1.

Your 2 choices to fix it:

1. Change from a `For...Next` to a `Do While` or `Do Until` loop
2. Simply delete the line in your loop that reads `GameNumber = GameNumber + 1`